# How can we show form error validations one after one in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-form-validation

I am new for angular and i have created one Custom EmailDomainError validator class and its working fine.

But problem is Email domain Error is showing along with Email validation error message how can i resolve this problem i am really confusing can some one help me please

I think i have to check email pattern is correct or not in my EmailDomainError class how can i ckeck that?if i think correct way and my complete code---https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvihqj

### ngOnInit

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.employeeForm = this.fb.group({
      fullName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(10)]],
      contactPreference: ['email'],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, emailDomainError]],
      phone: [''],
      skills: this.fb.group({
        skillName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        experienceInYears: ['', [Validators.required]],
        proficiency: ['', [Validators.required]]
      })
    });
```

### This object contains all the validation messages for this form

```
 formErrors = {
    'fullName': '',
    'email': '',
    'phone': '',
    'skillName': '',
    'experienceInYears': '',
    'proficiency': ''
  };


     validationMessages = {
        'fullName': {
          'required': 'Full Name is required.',
          'minlength': 'Full Name must be greater than 2 characters.',
          'maxlength': 'Full Name must be less than 10 characters.'
        },
        'email': {
          'required': 'Email is required.',
          'email': 'Valid Email id is required.',
          'emailDomainError': 'Email domain should be karvy.com'
        },
        'phone': {
          'required': 'Phone number is required.'
        },
        'skillName': {
          'required': 'Skill Name is required.',
        },
        'experienceInYears': {
          'required': 'Experience is required.',
        },
        'proficiency': {
          'required': 'Proficiency is required.',
        },
      };
```

### emailDomainError

```
function emailDomainError(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
  const email: string = control.value;
  const domain: string = email.substring(email.lastIndexOf("@") + 1);
  if (email === '' || domain === "karvy.com") {
    return null;
  } else {
    return { "emailDomainError": true };
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: hi Abhiram i will help you with please start a chat with me and i will you with this

Comment: yeah did you understand my probmlem?

Comment: actully i understand what you trying to do but i need more info to help in this

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: can  you update your code on stackblitz so i can update it

Comment: FormDomainError() function have to check either email validate or not can you please see that code once?

Comment: so want All email address enter in text box should be belongs to karvy.com

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvihqj

Comment: where is this FormDomainError() function

Comment: please check i posted my code in stackblitz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184464/discussion-between-harkesh-kumar-and-abhiram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi AbhiRam I Update your code here is link for [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iobylu)**

***In Form Group Update this like***

```
email: ['', [Validators.required, emailError, emailDomainError]],
```

***Function Code change like this***
*

```
*
 * emailDomainValidations
 * @param control 
 */

function emailDomainError(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
  const email: string = control.value;
  if (email && email.indexOf("@") != -1) {
    let [_, domain] = email.split("@");
    if (domain !== "karvy.com") {
      return {
        "emailDomainError": true,
       // "email": false
      };
    }

    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
function emailError(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
  const email: string = control.value;

  if( email.length <3 && email.length >=1){
    return { "email" : true}
  }
  else{
    return null;
  }

}
```